# Python Compare 2 Columns And Write A 4th Column With Values From 3rd Column (pandas )

Tags: python, pandas

Python Compare 2 Columns And Write A 4th Column With Values From 3rd Column If Column 1 Matches Column 2.
I have Two sheets in excel . First Sheet looks like

[image: 1]

second sheets looks like

[image: 2]

I need to convert this formula into pandas formula. The formula which generate etype is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A:A,0),2),"herbs").
```

Comment: Hey Kriti, 

The example shared is a little confusing, when you mention `match`, what are you referring to? 

It would be better if you can share the condition that you are trying to match the columns with. If your `type` column type is deduced from the `fruits column` Then it's better than you create a separate dictionary or dataframe for comparison instead.

Comment: HI ahjim0m0, I have edited the question . I need to change 
 =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A:A,0),2),"herbs") into pandas formula.

Comment: Hey Kriti, 

I think I understand where you are coming from, do refer to the answer below and see if I am getting you right.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is still slightly confusing but I hope I am getting this correctly. Your idea is that you would like to compare a list of items that can either be fruit or herbs, and you have a list of fruits.

Using the list of fruits, you would like to then check it against your list of items to return the `etype` which should be a `fruit` if it matches any item in the list of fruits or `herb` otherwise.

If I am correct, you may refer to this suggested code below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Importing your data with pandas
main_df = pd.read_csv(filename, sheetname = 'Sheet1') # Sheet 1 should be all items
fruits_df = pd.read_csv(filename, sheetname = 'Sheet2') # fruits sheet

# Convert your fruits into a list since we know they are all fruits
fruit_lst = fruits_df['fruits'].tolist()

# Iterate through your main list of items and check if they are a fruit
for i in range(len(main_df)):
   # Update 'herb' -> 'fruit' if it matches
   if main_df['herbs'][i] in fruit_lst:
      main_df['etype'][i] = 'fruit'
```

Generating some samples from your screenshots, this is what the code should return.

Before, the dataframe would look something like this:

[image: Before_check]

After the check against the fruit list, you should get the result you are looking for:
[image: After_check]

Hope this helps, though do try to share clearer details/screenshots in the future as well to help others understand your question!